# update product details not working CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a fuction on the CodeIgniter framework so users are able to edit/update product detail information. But when I submit the form I get a blank page and the product isn't updated in my database. I couldn't find a mistake myself.

Here is my view file form (cadeaubewerken.php):

```
  <table class="aanbieding-cadeau">

    <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "KdGwController/update_product"; ?>" method="post">
    <tr>
        <h4>Cadeau naam</h4>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'value' => $product["product_naam"] , 'size'=>25));?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'product_id', 'name'=>'product_id', 'value' => $product['product_id']));?>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_open_multipart('Product/upload'); ?> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>Kies een categorie</h4>
            <select name="category_id">
            <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) :
            if ($category->id ==  $product["category_id"]){
            echo '<option value="'.$category->id .'" selected>' . $category->name . '</option>';
            }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$category->id .'">'.$category->name . '</option>';
            }
            endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td><h4>Ophaal plaats</h4><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'value' => $product["ophaal_plaats"], 'size'=>25));?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'value' => $product['ophaal_plaats']));?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Gebruik adres van mijn account</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <h4>Huidig cadeau profiel foto</h4>
         <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>Cadeau profiel foto veranderen</h4>
            <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'value' =>$product['product_beschrijving'], 'size'=>25));?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'value' => $product['product_beschrijving']));?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Cadeau bewerken!" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

This is my controller file (KdGwController.php):

```
<?php


class KdGwcontroller extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $this->load->model('Update_product_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  }


  public function details_bewerken($product_id) {
    //load the Product_model
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

    //get product details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'cadeaubewerken';
    $this->load->view('cadeaubewerken',$data); 
  }

   public function update_product() {
     $id= $this->input->post('product_id');
     $data = array(
     'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
     'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
     'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
     );

    }

}
```

And this is my model file : (Update_product_model.php):

```
<?php

class Update_product_model extends CI_Model {

    function update_product($id,$data){
        $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('products', $data);
        header ('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io//AlleCadeausController');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what was the problem explain more...?

Comment: Just to point out your naming your controller wrong follow the file and class naming method explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling function update_product() of Update_product_model.php from KdGwController.php

Change this in your controller...

```
public function update_product() {

 $id= $this->input->post('product_id');
 $data = array(
 'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
 'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
 'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
 );
 $this->Update_product_model->update_product($id,$data); // this line you missed

}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to add `update` in model.

Also, your controller `update` function should be like

```
public function update_product() {
    $id= $this->input->post('product_id');
    $data = array(
        'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
        'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
        'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
     );

    // here I am assuming that `Product` is model
     $this->Product->where($id);
     $this->Product->update($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not call model function in your controller.

Change your controller `update_product()` function like this

```
public function update_product() {

     $id= $this->input->post('product_id');
     $data = array(
     'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
     'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
     'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
     );
     $this->Update_product_model->update_product($id,$data);

}
```